# Como funcionam e qual o conceito das streams no PHP

Tags: php, característica-linguagem, stream

Gostaria de saber como funciona e qual o conceito de streams. Já utilizei streams para pegar o input, também sei que existem outras para controlar o output. Entretanto, gostaria de conhecer a teoria e de onde vem a ideia no PHP.

OBS: Gostaria de saber qual a ideia de streams no geral e não somente em relação a input e output através do protocolo `php://`.

Desde já, agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isto não tem haver com PHP, *input* e *output* são uso básico em qualquer programa de computador, em PHP existem os protocolos para facilitar:

- `php://stdin`
- `php://stdout`

e podem ser usado com `fopen`, `file_get_contents` (ler), `file_put_contents` (gravar) entre outras funções de leitura (como `copy`).

Agora para HTTP, ou seja, páginas WEB, você deve usar:

- `php://input`
- `php://output`

Que podem ser usado com `fopen`, `file_get_contents` (ler), `file_put_contents` (gravar).

O PHP pode trabalhar com web como pode trabalhar em terminais (como um programa comum), então ao usar `php://input` em WEB você obterá o payload de requisições como POST e PUT, se enviou isto via requisição HTTP:

```
POST /foo/bar.php HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

foobar=boobaz&toofoo=ever
```

O `file_get_contents('php://input')` retornaria:

```
"foobar=boobaz&toofoo=ever"
```

Comment: @rcs é impossivel editar comentários com mais de 5 minutos, ou seja eles tem mais de 3 meses, então o tempo já passou bastante, mas vou excluir pq acho que conversamos o que era necessário e podemos seguir a partir daqui, ando sem tempo, mas em breve irei enumerar os wrappers e irei te notificar ;)

Comment: @rcs opa tudo sim, feito, tentei explicar de forma mais clara na resposta, espero que ajude.